# How to say 'or' in Japanese?

Tags: grammar

I want to know how to say "or" in Japanese. For example, there is a sentence like this:

"Bathing in the sea, or just viewing it, whatever is fine."

I only finish N4 only and don't know anything other than とか…とか in this situation.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

using `または` is normal to say OR.

`か` can also be used.

- A `か` B
- A `または` B

Comment: Also あるいは, もしくは, それとも, as mentioned in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15377).